# Understanding Kmeans prediction

Tags: predictive-models, k-means

I am using the Kaggle [heart disease dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/fedesoriano/heart-failure-prediction) and using Kmeans to understand the clustering of the data.  I used several of the continuous variable columns and the target (age, maxHR, cholesterol, restingBP, HeartDisease).  In R I run my dataset with the kmeans function and 4 clusters per other analysis that 4 is optimal.

What I am struggling to understand is what I can actually predict here.  If I put in values for all the variables including the target, I can get the cluster that the "predicted" option belongs to.  But what if I want to input all features, except the target, and I don't know the cluster or the target.  Can I use the model to tell me both.  I would think that all the features would determine a cluster and the cluster helps me figure out the target.  Does this make sense or am I thinking of this the wrong way?

Comment: Kmeans is not a method to predict a continuous target. It is a method for unsupervised classification that clusters the data. You can predict the cluster for a new observation by assigning it to the closest mean, however it's not the task of Kmeans to "figure out the target". (One could imagine to run a prediction method within a cluster, but as far as I know that's not a well established approach and may be far from the best way of predicting the target.)

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful.  So if we try to "predict" something with kmeans, it would only be which cluster it's in?

Comment: So I'd say. ("Comments must be at least 15 characters in length";-)